# Convert binary two's complement data into integer in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, binary, accelerometer, twos-complement

I have some binary data (twos complement) coming from an accelerometer and I need to convert it to an integer.  Is there a standard library function which does this, or do I need to write my own code?

For example: I receive an NSData object from the acclerometer, which when converted to hex looks like this:

```
C0088001803F
```

Which is a concatenation of 3 blocks of 2-byte data:

```
x = C008
y = 8001
z = 803F
```

Focussing on the x-axis only:

```
hex = C008
decimal = 49160
binary = 1100000000001000
twos complement = -16376
```

Is there a standard function for converting from C008 in twos complement directly to -16376?

Thank you.

Comment: Use NSData to convert binary data into any other...

Comment: Can you show the type of the binary data? It is an instance of NSData? It is a int[]? It is only one integer or more than one?

Comment: So you get it as a string or 2s complent? Please simply dump your instance of NSData and add it to the Q. It is hard to answer your questions without assumptions without that.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I don't have the NSData to dump out to you, but when I convert it to hex it looks like the above.  I'm not sure why its important what the dump of the NSData looks like - the question is how I can convert a hex value of C008 to -16376.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: 1. You can dump it using -description. 2. Yes, it is important: --->Can you show the type of the binary data?<--- --->So you get it as a string or 2s comp lent?<--- c008 is *not* binary data. It isn't And it can be 0xC008 *or* "C008". What's the problem to tell us?

Comment: `int`, in Objective-C, *is* "binary 2s complement".  The only thing you need to do is to sign-extend the value if it's negative.  Generally this would be done by placing it in an `int` variable, shifting up N bits so that the sign bit is in the topmost bit, then shifting down N bits.  (The only trick is knowing how bit your `int` is -- could be 32 or 64 bits.  Probably best to use `int32_t`.)

Comment: @theDuncs i am also facing this problem that how to convert hex into twos complement directly . did you get the solution ? can you guide me through this ?

Comment: @Moxarth Hey, check the answer below.  It works BEAUTIFULLY.

Comment: @theDuncs i really did not get it what the happening there with the data conversions .so i asked you that how it is done . if you have implemented that only then could you elaborate more about that code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
const int8_t* bytes = (const int8_t*) [nsDataObject bytes];

int32_t x = (bytes[0] << 8) + (0x0FF & bytes[1]);
x = x << 16;
x = x >> 16;

int32_t y = (bytes[2] << 8) + (0x0FF & bytes[3]);
y = y << 16;
y = y >> 16;

int32_t z = (bytes[4] << 8) + (0x0FF & bytes[5]);
z = z << 16;
z = z >> 16;
```

This assumes that the values really are "big-endian" as suggested in the question.