# Hex to 2's complement in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, twos-complement

I'm trying to convert a hex value e.g. `0xFAE8` to a 2's complement decimal i.e. `-1304`.

I've tried looking at this [Convert binary two's complement data into integer in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931789/convert-binary-twos-complement-data-into-integer-in-objective-c)
but I don't really get how the byte-shifting enables the conversion to be done properly. I hope there can be an explanation or a simpler way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: i am also facing this problem that how to convert hex into twos complement directly . did you get the solution ? can you guide me through this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to convert a hex value e.g. 0xFAE8 to a 2's complement decimal i.e. -1304.

If the Most Significant Bit (MSB) is set, then you have to flip or invert all the bits and add 1. Here's the general algorithm:

```
if (msb_is_set) then

  x = to_integer(...)
  x = ~x
  x = x + 1

else

  x = to_integer(...)

endif
```

It omits overflow checks, so be sure to handle those cases in production code.

You can test if the msb or high bit is set with:

```
if((0x80 & byte[0]))

    /* high bit is set */

endif
```